# ListView onScroll при создании списка

Tags: android

При создании списка сразу срабатывает событие `onScroll`. Как побороть?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего костылями(то есть никак). 
Причина всего этого состоит вот в чем. Вот исходный код метода `setOnScrollListener`

```
    public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener l) {
        mOnScrollListener = l;
        invokeOnItemScrollListener();
    }
```

В свою очередь код `invokeOnItemScrollListener();`

```
    void invokeOnItemScrollListener() {
        if (mFastScroller != null) {
            mFastScroller.onScroll(this, mFirstPosition, getChildCount(), mItemCount);
        }
        if (mOnScrollListener != null) {
            mOnScrollListener.onScroll(this, mFirstPosition, getChildCount(),
                mItemCount);
        }
        onScrollChanged(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    }
```

То есть сразу после установки лиснера, он вызывается.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Пришлось немного накостылять.

Comment: Можно, на пример, сделать какой-то флаг(boolean), который по умолчанию будет = false, и встанет в true, при первом срабатывании лиснера. И в самом лиснере - если флаг == false, то установить его в true, иначе - делать все, что нужно делать при скролле.

Answer (score 0):

.....

```
private Boolean userScrolled = false;
```

......

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {         
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){          
                int action = event.getAction();

                if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {                  
                    userScrolled = true;
                }

                return false;               
            }
        });
```

и в onScroll примерно так:

```
@Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)   {

        if (!userScrolled) return;

    }
```